# Using CodeIgniter and PHP, is there a way to issue a redirect to the client and continue executing the present script?

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

I have a page which handles form input. It does a few things, sends a few emails, and redirects the client to another page. Things work well.

The issue I that sending email is slow, and if I have to send a couple emails, the response time is unacceptable. I would like to redirect the client to the result page, and then send the emails. Unfortunately, the `redirect()` call in CodeIgniter ends execution.

Is there a way to do a 302 redirect and allow the execution of the script to continue?

It is important that the 302 redirect headers get flushed out. It would be OK, but is not required, that the connection be closed. What is important that the user gets redirected *before* the emails get sent, in order to not have to wait for the email sending to finish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think using a message queue would be more appropriate than having a possible zombie process sitting there. Essentially when this action is taken dump a job into a job queue with the body of the e-mail, who it's going to, the subject etc. Then have a cron job set up to read this queue every two minutes, say, and send out the e-mail.

You can also look into using something like the Simple Queue Service from Amazon (http://aws.amazon.com/sqs/faqs/#What_can_I_do_with_Amazon_SQS) along with the Simple E-Mail Service to create a scaleable solution.

Comment: Your solution is most definitely the correct way of doing this. However, I am looking for a quick solution I can implement for the meantime, as we would rather not dedicate the time to developing a MQ based solution.